# Appengine Python2.7: Failed to publish container id

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I am getting the following error while deploying the service to appengine. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version=v1
```

Used the above command to deploy the service.

```
Updating service [test] (this may take several minutes)...failed. 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Failed to publish container id.
```

Comment: What version of gcloud are you running?

Comment: Is the first time you've tried to deploy this instance? Have you ever successfully deployed it? Have you successfully deployed other instances in this project?

Comment: also, does this still happen if you specify `--project 
 [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]` in your command? (where project id is the slug assigned to your project...it'll show up in your GCP console URL, formatted something like 'ham-sandwich'